# Remove parenthesis and brackets from multiple directories

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I'm trying to find a way to remove parenthesis and brackets from directories, but they don't have all the same pattern. 
Some are like this: `(1234) ABC [xyz]`. Others are like this `[xyz] ABC (1234)(987)`.

Edit: The desired output would be `ABC`

How can I do this?

Comment: Add some examples and your desired output from those...

Comment: Do you have duplicate directory names ? For example, `(1234) ABC [xyz]` and `[xyz] ABC (1234)` , if you remove items with brackets, both become `ABC`, so you basically might overwrite one with the other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `rename` to remove any of those characters wherever they occur with alternation

```
rename -n 's/\(|\[|\]|\)//g' *
```

You need to escape the brackets and parentheses.

Remove `-n` after testing to really do the renaming.

To remove all the characters within brackets or parentheses

```
rename -n 's/\(.*\)|\[.*\]//g' *
```

To also remove spaces (to change `(1234) ABC [xyz]` to `ABC`)

```
rename -n 's/\(.*\)|\[.*\]| //g' *
```

Comment: The output always have a  ')' as the last character, is this because I'm not escaping the parentheses properly? Other than that it worked.

Comment: show me your command @AvantGarde :)

Comment: I tried using `rename -n 's/\(|\[|\]|\)//g' *`.

Comment: I mistook the parenthesis after the output as being part of the output. So there was no problem with the code.

Comment: oh I see! yeah that can be confusing @AvantGarde :)

Comment: without `-n` worked. `rename 's/\(.*\)|\[.*\]//g' *` and `rename 's/\(.*\)|\[.*\]| //g' *` :)

Comment: @Lnux the `-n` is to test it, before you actually rename anything

Comment: I read your answer **Remove `-n` after testing to really do the renaming.**

Comment: @Lnux So what do you mean then, why did you say it works without `-n`? I am confused by your comment!

Comment: Actually i was trying with `-n` and not getting the point testing but then noticed the output after running the command.  So confusion cleared.